# Android sends the same message two times

Tags: android, sms

as asked in question I am using following code I dont know why it send the sms two times

```
sendButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {   
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            msg = messgeText.getText().toString();
            no = phoneNumber.getText().toString();
            if(msg.length() > 0 && no.length() > 0)
                sendSMS(no, msg);
        }
    });
```

and here sendSMS

```
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
{                       
    SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);  
    Log.d("Insend", "sms sent");
    Toast.makeText(SendSMS.this, "SMS Successfully sent.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Where did you put that? Is it in your onCreate?

Comment: Where did you put this.. onClick method or onTouch method or in both?clear it first..

Comment: I have updated my post is it clear now

Answer (score 0):

I think handler is getting called twice. so you have to figure out why ? suppose say you are using onKeyListener one has to differentiate whether it is onKeyUp or onKeyDown. Since you are using onClick , I am not sure why it is getting called twice !

Comment: Hi as you can see the I have put a log that log is printed only one time so its not called again and again

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem with a HTC tatoo phone.

Using the following code, strangely solved the problem!

```
private void sendSMS(String to, String text) {
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    ArrayList<String> messages = sms.divideMessage(text);
    sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(to, null, messages, null, null);
}
```

Notice the use of *`sendMultipartTextMessage`*. It works with small text messages also!